# Loop in a pseudocode

Tags: solution-verification, programming

I got the pseudocode:

[image]

With the array:

[image]

Then I have to find if $n=64$  how many times the while loop can be run at most with the call exists$(A,n,x)$? I think it's $0$ because we get $lo=0$, $hi=63$ and $mid=floor(\frac{63}{2})=31$ and $A[31]$ is not in our array, and we can not make any loop? Or what?

Comment: That algorithm has an Undefined Behaviour when `A[mid]` doesn't exist. It should be assumed that n is the size of the array, otherwise the input is invalid. And so this question cannot be answered. Btw the question asks about the number of iterations which is at least 1 when n>0 (assuming the input is correct).

Comment: Thank you, I see. I will write that in stead of '$0$ iterations'

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:coding-theory].